# Enlarge controls in flow layout panel when flow layout panel enlarge

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a question about my c# winform. When I enlarge my flow layout panel, I want my controls in it enlarge depends on my size of the flow layout panel. How can I do that?

Comment: You may want to use a TableLayoutPanel instead. It's much simpler to make child controls auto-size. The FlowLayoutPanel is not made for this.

Answer (score 0):

For DataGridView changes with the size of the form,you could use control [Control.Anchor Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Anchor).

> Gets or sets the edges of the container to which a control is bound
> and determines how a control is resized with its parent.

Set the property Anchor of the DataGridView to Top, Left, Right, and it will resize with the container. If your DataGridView is placed in a container (panel), then the panel should also be anchored.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please help me, sorry about that. Thank you so much!